# Do I need a physical switch to configure vlans in esxi

Tags: linux, esxi, vlan

My home network is very simple with a cable modem and a physical wireless router with four ethernet interfaces. I have a server with esxi, installed connected to one of the interfaces. I do not have a physical switch.

All my VMs are connected to "VM Network" virtual machine group, and I am able to access VMs from other computers on the network. My network is 192.168.1.0/24

I want to create vlans in esxi , is it possible to do this with out a physical. When I created virtual machine groups with different VLAN IDs , the machines are not assigned ips.

Comment: What is your actual question: Whether VLAN traffic will maintain the tagging in your physical network? How to create this entirely within ESXi? Something else? What is the DHCP server on your network?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an option similar to Hyper-V within Esxi to create and configure a Virtual Switch.  Your virtual switch can be Private / Internal / External depending on the communication you want between the VM's and the host machine / WAN; but creation of a virtual switch will allow you to assign VLAN's and obtain IPs

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I've run into on my own personal lab as well. It's hard to say whether your equipment will support it. You can have multiple virtual switches (vSS) but what really matters are the VLANs. Your default VLAN is usually VLAN1. Your home networking equipment typically won't recognize VLAN traffic so one of two things will happen: either it will strip the VLAN headers and not pass traffic or pass it as VLAN1, or it will ignore the VLAN headers and pass the traffic as if it were a trunk port.
The next problem you'll run into is if you want multiple VLANs to access the internet, you have to be able to tag the VLAN to a VLAN routing interface. So for this you will either need a router with VTP or a layer 3 switch. 
What I ended up doing in my lab was to set up a Sonicwall SOHO router behind my cable modem and a GS108Tv2 NETGEAR managed switch. Now I have multiple internet-accessible networks. I make sure my stuff is gigabit as well so it will support iSCSI storage too.

If you need more advice, feel free to message me.

Answer (score 0):

Without a physical switch or router capable of inter-VLAN routing, it is not as straightforward as creating VLANs on vSphere.  However, you should be able to build a VM that can handle the VLAN routing for you.  I would use Linux.  This VM should have a virtual network card attached for each concerned VLAN.  If those VLANs must also be able to communicate with the outside world, then this virtual machine will have to be able to handle that routing as well.  This could be NAT/PAT using iptables on Linux.  There may be prepackaged distributions which could handle this for you, some with a nice web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Vlans can be internal to your esxi host only.

If you want to be able to route to those vlans from your physical network, then run a virtual router in your esx environment which is connected to each vlan. run static routes from your cable modem to those networks next hop virtual router vlan1.

Many machines could be your virtual router. I'd recommend a *nix router distro, pfsense is the only thing I can think of right now. In my labs I run cisco's CSR1000V but the throughput on an unlicensed csr1000v is probably not what you're looking for.